# Simple line rendering fails while trying to render pixel coordinates

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

I am sorry to carry this here, but I spend around 7 hours maybe for a really easy thing. Maybe some of you identify the problem.

I try to render some pixel coordinates to screen. The code is below.

For a 800x600 screen. Simply trying to calculate the position of the lines, and then to render it to the screen.

For example: Point A(400, 300, 0) and point B(500,300,0) shall be a simple black line from the center of the screen to the right.

As I call this class function in render, I thought I might be creating a separate rendering session. However, when I write something such as glCleanColor, the background changes.

```
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
```

Vertex shader:

```
const GLchar *vertex_shader =
    "#version 410\n"
    "layout (location = 0) in vec3 pos;\n"
    "layout (location = 1) in vec4 col;\n"
    "uniform mat4 projection;\n"
    "out vec4 Frag_Color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    Frag_Color = col;\n"
    "    gl_Position =projection*vec4(pos.xyz,1);\n"
    "}\n";
```

Fragment Shader:

```
const GLchar *fragment_shader =
    "#version 410\n"
    "in vec4 Frag_Color;\n"
    "layout (location = 0) out vec4 Out_Color;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "    Out_Color = Frag_Color;\n"
    "}\n";
```

Vertex structure

```
struct Vrtx
{
    float pos[3];
    float col[4] = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
};
```

coord axis class:

```
class CoordinateAxis
{
public:
    void coordinate_axis()
    {
        vertices.resize(6);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            vertices[2 * i].pos[0] = 400;
            vertices[2 * i].pos[1] = 300;
            vertices[2 * i].pos[2] = 0;
        }
        vertices[1].pos[0] = 500;
        vertices[1].pos[1] = 300;
        vertices[1].pos[2] = 0;
        vertices[3].pos[0] = 400;
        vertices[3].pos[1] = 400;
        vertices[3].pos[2] = 0;
        vertices[3].pos[0] = 400;
        vertices[3].pos[1] = 430;
        vertices[3].pos[2] = 100;

        setupRender();
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);
        glDrawElements(GL_LINE, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
        glBindVertexArray(0);
        glUseProgram(0);
    }
    CoordinateAxis()
    {
        initShaderProgram();
    };

private:
    void initShaderProgram()
    {
        // Vertex shader
        GLuint vHandle = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(vHandle, 1, &vertex_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(vHandle);

        // Fragment shader
        GLuint fHandle = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        glShaderSource(fHandle, 1, &fragment_shader, NULL);
        glCompileShader(fHandle);

        // Create Program
        handleProgram = glCreateProgram();
        glAttachShader(handleProgram, vHandle);
        glAttachShader(handleProgram, fHandle);
        glLinkProgram(handleProgram);

        attribLocationProj = glGetUniformLocation(handleProgram, "projection");

        glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
        // CreateBuffers
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboHandle);
        glGenBuffers(1, &iboHandle);
    }
    void setupRender()
    {
        GLint last_viewport[4];
        glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, last_viewport);
        float L = last_viewport[0];
        float R = L + last_viewport[2];
        float B = last_viewport[1];
        float T = B + last_viewport[3];

        const float ortho_projection[4][4] =
            {
                {2.0f / (R - L), 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f},
                {0.0f, 2.0f / (T - B), 0.0f, 0.0f},
                {0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f},
                {(R + L) / (L - R), (T + B) / (B - T), 0.0f, 1.0f},
            };
        glUseProgram(handleProgram);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(attribLocationProj, 1, GL_FALSE, &ortho_projection[0][0]);
        glBindVertexArray(VAO);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, iboHandle);
        glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indices.size() * sizeof(GLuint), indices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle);
        glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vrtx), vertices.data(), GL_STATIC_DRAW);

        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboHandle);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vrtx), 0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, vertices.size() * sizeof(Vrtx), (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
    }

    std::vector<Vrtx> vertices;
    std::vector<GLuint> indices;
    GLuint handleProgram, VAO, vboHandle, iboHandle, attribLocationProj;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GL_LINE` is not a valid primitive type. `GL_LINE` is a mode for [`glPolygonMode`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glPolygonMode.xhtml).
A valid [line primitive](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Primitive#Line_primitives) type is `GL_LINES`:

<s>`glDrawElements(GL_LINE, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);`</s>

```cpp
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

Furthermore there is an issue when you set up the array of vertex attribute data by [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml). The 5th parameter (*strid*) is the byte offset between consecutive attribute tuples, rather than the size of the buffer. `sizeof(Vrtx)` rather than `vertices.size() * sizeof(Vrtx)`:

```cpp
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vrtx), 0);
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vrtx), (void *)(3*sizeof(float)));
```

---

Note, the array of indices seems to be empty. Either initialize the array of indices:

```cpp
indices = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

or use [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml) instead:

```cpp
glDrawArrays(GL_LINES, 0, 6);
```

Comment: Can I hug you somehow after I complain the gods about this issue ?

Comment: @sariug There is a further issue in `glVertexAttribPointer`. I've extended the answer.